# How much free space do I need to install Mavericks 10.9.4?

Tags: macos, software-update

I have downloaded OS X Mavericks 10.9.4 which is 283 MB, and I have free space of 168 GB and I am getting an error as shown:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than enough space on your disk

I'd very much like to see a picture of your 'About this Mac screen', from the  Apple menu, just to be certain you're heading in the right direction.

It should look something like this…

[image]

Also, you'd be better off installing the [10.9.5 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1760) which will install all updates from 10.9.0 to 10.9.5 without needing any intermediate steps.

*After comments & posted picture:*
You cannot jump over an update using just the delta update, only using a combo.

Comment: I've added screenshot you asked for

Comment: I'd try the combo updater I linked above. I'm not sure the delta updater can jump updates 10.9.2 to 10.9.4 without 10.9.3 first. The combo definitely can.

Comment: yea the combo did, I tried yesterday night and now I am on 10.9.5

Comment: Glad you got there :)